# Create a simulink bus from a structure

Tags: matlab, simulink, bus

I have measurement data that is stored in form of hierarchical structures containing MATLAB timeseries objects.
For example:

```
MyData
  - TimeSeries1
  - TimeSeries2
  - MyHierarchicalData
     -- TimeSeries3
```

To use those in Simulink I use a from file block that reads these structures from a single file. However, to select signals out of those, the bus selector block needs a corresponding bus object. As the bus object more or less corresponds to the structure, I would like to know whether it is possible to generate a bus object out of my structured timeseries data. If the bus only contained a few variables, doing this by hand would not be a problem but the bus contains roughly 250 elements.

My first guess would be the Simulink API but I thought this problem occured more frequently and there exists an easier solution. If there is none and I am on the wrong trail I would appreciate some feedback as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the answer that I posted to my own (somewhat similar) question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17152383/1710688

Since you already have a structure of timeseries objects you need to use the function `fieldnames` ([see MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html)) to get values for each timeseries object. 
You have hierarchical structure so you will also need to use the function `class` ([see MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html)) to check if it is a timeseries object or a struct object in which case you need to again look at its fieldnames. I am not exactly sure on how to create a hierarchical signal bus object but hopefully this link on [Using Bus Objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-bus-objects.html) can help.

Hope that helps.